# Beamer . No pages of output

Tags: beamer

It's my first time using `beamer` for my thesis presentation, I started writing the program below but it's not working , every time I compile it, the error message "No pages of output" appears.
the Program:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\title{Présentation du projet de fin d'étude}
\subtitle{Commande adaptative de la machine asynchrone}
\author{présenté par:\\
GUENDOUZ \\
Sous la direction de :\\
Pr A.BOUHENNA}
\institute{Ecole National Polythechnique d'Oran MAURICE AUDIN}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\section{Plan de travail}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Plan de travail}
\begin{itemize}
\item Présentation du thème (Thème,Problématique et objectifs)
\item Présentation de la machine asynchrone 
\item La commande vectorielle par orientation de flux indirect(théorie et application)
\item La commande adaptative (théorie et application)
\item Conclusion
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten to add the `\end{itemize}` at the end of the list.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\title{Présentation du projet de fin d'étude}
\subtitle{Commande adaptative de la machine asynchrone}
\author{présenté par:\\
GUENDOUZ \\
Sous la direction de :\\
Pr A.BOUHENNA}
\institute{Ecole National Polythechnique d'Oran MAURICE AUDIN}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle % <-- add this to make the title slide

\section{Plan de travail}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Plan de travail}
\begin{itemize}
\item Présentation du thème (Thème,Problématique et objectifs)
\item Présentation de la machine asynchrone 
\item La commande vectorielle par orientation de flux indirect(théorie et application)
\item La commande adaptative (théorie et application)
\item Conclusion
\end{itemize} % <-- this was missing
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much , it worked ! but now i have another problem where the first slide didn't appear

Comment: @asmaa There is just one slide in your code. Add `\maketitle` before the `\section` to get the slide with title etc.

Comment: yup i have added it and it worked thank you again !